Issue with Replicate.ai API Returning ReadableStream Instead of Image URL in Next.js
I'm working on a Next.js project that generates images using the Replicate.ai API. Although images are generated correctly on the Replicate.ai dashboard, the API response in my Next.js serverless function returns a ReadableStream instead of the expected image URL.
API Route (route.jsx):
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Replicate from "replicate";

export async function POST(req) {
  try {
    const { prompt } = await req.json();

    const replicate = new Replicate({
      auth: process.env.REPLICATE_API_TOKEN
    });

    const input = {
      prompt: prompt,
      height: 1280,
      width: 1024,
      num_outputs: 1,
    };

    const output = await replicate.run(
      "bytedance/sdxl-lightning-4step:5599ed30703defd1d160a25a63321b4dec97101d98b4674bcc56e41f62f35637",
      { input }
    );

    console.log("Generated Image:", output);

    return NextResponse.json({ result: output[0] });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating image:", error);
  }
}

Frontend Function in page.jsx:
const GenerateImage = async () => {
  let images = [];
  videoSCRIPT.forEach(async (element) => {
    await axios.post('/api/generate-image', { prompt: element?.imagePrompt })
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log("Frontend Response:", resp.data.result); 
        images.push(resp.data.result);
      });
  });
  console.log(images);
  setImageList(images);
  setLoading(false);
}

What I See in the Console:

Generated Image: [ ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false } ] Frontend Response: {},{}

What I Expected:

The generated image URL to appear in the browser console and be passed back correctly.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Checked the Replicate.ai dashboard—images are generated successfully.

Confirmed the API key and endpoint are correct.





Did you try providing a static prompt like prompt: "a photo of vibrant artistic graffiti on a wall saying "SD3 medium"" ?

Yes, but it's generating images on the website and not returning anything on the server.
